# Loading a child view triggers the root ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

My application consists of three screens, the main menu which is the root view which presents an option to select the second view.

The second view is a UITableView and if a cell in the table is selected the third view, the detail view ,  loads.

When the third view loads, functions contained in the root viewController's 'viewDidLoad' are triggered, why might this be ?

I have tried various segues ( from the tableview to the detail view ) but the result is the same, here is my current implementation :

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nameOfSegue"]) {
          UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
          NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForCell:cell];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        EntryViewController *TitleViewController = (EntryViewController *) navigationController.topViewController;
        TitleViewController.entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Do segues inherently trigger the root viewController or am I looking in the wrong place ?

Comment: Just curious: what happens if you remove `UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        EntryViewController *TitleViewController = (EntryViewController *) navigationController.topViewController;` and replace it with `EntryViewController *entryVC = (EntryViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;`

Comment: I get an error : " ... unrecognized selector sent to instance ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be doing something wrong. As I'm concerned viewDidLoad() is called only once, before the view is rendered on screen. Are you sure viewDidLoad() of the first controller is being called?

Perhaps to help you more a screenshot of your Main.storyboard and the full code of the controllers would be useful.

From Apple documentation:

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view
>   hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the
>   view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically
>   in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform
>   additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

Comment: When I remove all the functions from the viewDidLoad of the third view it stops calling the functions in the root viewController, so you must be right. I have an NSLog(@"root view triggered "); set up so I'm pretty confident that it is actually calling the root viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using StoryBoard? 
You may set the third viewController's class to the first viewController's so when the third viewController showing up `viewDidLoad` called.